# Можно ли использовать python код в Spring приложениях?

Tags: python, spring

Разрабатываю систему с использованием алгоритмов машинного обучения, код написан на python с использованием Tensorflow, OpenCV.
Далее необходимо создать веб-приложение. Поскольку я знаком со Spring, мне бы не хотелось создавать приложение с использованием Flask.
Вопрос: Можно ли использовать скрипт python при создании Spring приложения, и если да то как?

Comment: Веб-приложение это веб-приложение. Ему до лампочки как и на чем работают его клиенты, лишь бы протокол передачи данных соблюдался.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_java?hl=ur

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-opencv